# Dell Sonicwall - X0 and X1 set to the same IP

Tags: router, sonicwall

So some mistakes were made and X0 and X1 have been set to the same IP, now we're unable to connect to the web interface for the sonic wall to undo the actions that were done.
Does anyone know if there's a way to undo what has been done without access? or will we have to hard reset the box.

Comment: Unplug x1 and try to connect again from x0

Comment: @yagmoth555 just tried that and didn't help unfortunately, i also unplugged X2 so the only one that was plugged in was X0 and still wasn't able to connect.

Comment: Ok, boot in config mode and connect to 192.168.168.192 and flush the config :/